# Question on Markov-Chain GATE (ST)-$2021$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

**Question:**  Let $\{X_n:n \ge0 \}$ be a time- homogeneous discrete  time Markov-chain with either finite or countable state space $S$. Then

$1.$ there is at least one recurrent state

$2.$ if there is an absorbing state, then there exists at least one stationary distribution

$3.$ if all states are positive recurrent, then there exists a unique stationary distribution

$4.$ If $\{X_n:n \ge0 \}$ is irreducible, $S=\{1,2\}$ and $[\pi_1 , \pi_2]$ is a stationary distribution, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} P\{X_n=i|X_0=i\}=\pi_i,$ for $i=1,2.$

*My Attempt:*

$1.$ I gave a counterexample. Take, $P=\left [ \begin{matrix} 1/2 & 1/2 &0 &0& \cdots \\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2&0 & \cdots \\ \vdots& \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \ddots \\ \end{matrix} \right ]$ with infinite state space $S$. Here, all states are transient.

$2.$ If there is an absorbing state, say state-$i$, so $d(i)=1$ and hence, state-$i$ is aperiodic. Since, every absorbing state is recurrent which implies Markov-chain has a recurrent, aperiodic state-$i$. I could not think further.

We first recall, "An irreducible positive recurrent Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution." See this[Theorem4,5](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee126/sp18/markov-chains.pdf).

$3.$ Take, $P= \left [ \begin{matrix}  1&0 \\ 1/2&1/2\\ \end{matrix} \right ]$. Here, all states are positive recurrent but it is infinitely stationary distributed.

$4.$ Really confused if we can apply theorem$5$.

The correct answer given in the key is $2$.

> Kindly help me to prove this second option and help me understanding the last option( I am confused) and please check if my approach for other options is fine. Is there any use of the "homogeneous" thing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I know that the chain given in option-$4$ is irreducible+finite $\implies $ positive recurrent and using above Theorem-$4$, we get a unique stationary distribution.

Comment: If $i$ is absorbing then $\pi_j=0$ for $j \neq i$ and $\pi_i=1$ defines a stationary distribution.

Comment: Hint for option $4$: Have a look at the chain with transition matrix $\ \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\ $.

Comment: @lonza leggiera  thanks, I got you. This chain is periodic with period $2$, therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} P\{X_n=i|X_0=i\}=2 \pi_i \ne \pi_i$, Right?

Comment: You're on the  right track, but since $\ P\big\{X_n=i\,\big|\,X_0=i\big\}\ $ alternates between the values $1$ (for even $\ n\ $) and $\ 0\ $(for odd $\ n\ $), so it has no limit as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.

Comment: @lonza leggiera This is the confusion. Please check the following statements if they are correct: (1)  A positive recurrent Markov chain converges to $\pi$ via $\pi_j=\lim_{n\to \infty} P \{X_n=j| X_0=i\}$ iff the chain is aperiodic.

Comment: (2) If $\{X_n\}$ is a positive recurrent and irreducible(*doubt!*)  Markov chain, then a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ exists and is given by $\pi_j =\frac{1}{\mu_{jj}} >0.$

Comment: (3) In irreducible, positive recurrent but *periodic* case, we still have that $\pi_j, j\ge 0$, are the unique non negative solution of the system $\pi =\pi P$. But, now the limiting probability will be given by $\lim_{n\to \infty} P\{X_{nd}=j| X_0=j\} =d \pi_j$, $d$ is the period of state-j.

Comment: ohhh I see, in 4th option, they are going in $n$-steps not in $nd$-steps, so we can not apply the above (3)rd result. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answers but I am answering to remove this question from unanswered que and for others if someone needs the answer in future.

For $(2)$, using [Kavi Rama Murty's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy) hint given in the comments:

If there is an absorbing satate-$i$ $\implies$ $i$ is a periodic, recurrent. We get, $\pi_j=0, \forall j\ne i$, and $\pi_i=1$. This gives a stationary distribution.

For $(4)$, use   [lonza leggiera's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/632373/lonza-leggiera) hint:

Given $\{X_n: n\ge0\}$ is irreducible with finite state space $S=\{1,2\}$ and it has a stationary distribution $\pi= [\pi_1, \pi_2]$. Note that the given chain may not be aperiodic, so we take a periodic chain with transition probability matrix $P=\left[ \begin{matrix} 0&1 \\ 1 &0\end{matrix} \right ]$. Here, $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1/2&1/2 \end{matrix} \right ]$ is a stationary distribution but this chain does not have a limiting distribution.